# Why is the jSignature div moved to the top left of the browser window?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap, and am trying add the jSignature widget to a form. I followed the instructions on their web site, which was to add a div (which in my case has an id of "signature") and then use the following...

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script type="text/javascript" src="libs/flashcanvas.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<script src="libs/jSignature.min.js"></script>
<div id="signature"></div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#signature").jSignature()
    })
</script>
```

The part of the form that contains the div looks like this...

```
<div class="form-group">
 <label for="signature"class = "col-md-2 control-label">Signature</label>
  <div class="col-md-10">
    <div id="signature"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is exactly the same format as the rest of the form.

However, when I look at this in a browser, the jSignature widget appears at the top left of the window, partially obscured by the Bootsrap navigation bar, instead of being next to the label as it should.

If I look at the source code, the signature div is in the right place, but the Chrome developer tools show that it has been moved to the very beginning of the body tag, which is presumably why it ends up where it does.

Anyone know why it's doing this? I want it to stay where it's supposed to be.

Comment: Inspect your `#signature` element to see if it has styling properties defined within a `style` attribute. If it does, its style is being altered by JavaScript.

Comment: `col-md` is used for content widths equal to or larger than 992px. Are you sure the section you have that content in is 992px or wider? If it's not, then it'll put the div after your label bellow. Also, we'd have to know what type of bootstrap navbar (if you're using a bootstrap navbar) in order to figure out why it's being obsucred.

Comment: A number of bootstrap toolbar implementations rely on styles like `body { padding-top:65px; }` so that the top content of the page is not obscured.

Comment: James - my signature div is as simple as it can be, it's a plain div tag with an id of "signature" and nothing else. Whilst trying to work out what was going wrong, I added some styling (height and width), but that was in a style section elsewhere on the page. If I don't set the height and width, it takes the full width of the window, but is still up at the top.

Comment: MattD, the content is less than 992px, but that shouldn't matter. The rest of the form is also less than that width, but all that happens is that the labels are on the left of the form elements on most devices, and above them on tweeny ones. Either way, all elements remain where they are supposed to be relative to the body structure. This widget is being moved completely out of place, and seems to end up right at the top of the body tag, outside of the form. I'm using a bootstrap navbar, but I don't think that's relevant, as the main problem is the widget being moved.

Comment: Perhaps you should include an image of what's happening to your widget? You'll also likely need to include more code that's relevant to these two items, because when I pop that code into Bootply, so long as the viewport is 992px or wider, the label for the signature stays inline with the div that's supposed to be next to it.

Comment: Thanks to all of you for the comments, but I just discovered this one, which works right out of the box! No point in fighting with one that doesn't work. This one also has a built-in method of detectign an empty signature, unlike jSignnature... http://keith-wood.name/signature.html